# Stop Tracking CVS Files Locally?

Tags: unix, version-control, cvs

I accidentally checked out a bunch of files in an undesired CVS directory, causing me to run out of disc space. How do I undo the action safely? Theoretically, I’d think running (Unix) rm -r on the dir and then redo’ing the checkout for the correct path would work but I don’t want to risk causing potential alterations to the repo itself. I can’t seem to find anything online that explains how to remove checked out files from local view only. Guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can just delete your local CVS checked out files.  Nothing on the CVS repository will be changed.  The CVS repository is only changed when you do a `cvs commit` command (and `cvs tag` and a few other CVS commands).

You can also move your local checked out files to another directory.